# Autofilter between date range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to autofilter some data between two Dates entered in a Userform (DTPicker)between two columns(One colum:start date; second column:end date) but my code seems Problem to recognise the date range.

I've searched the old threads but nothing seems to answer my question. If anyone has any thoughts I'd appreciate hearing from you. The relevant bits of the code are below. Many thanks

My Excel table and userform:

[image]

Required Output: In userform when select Start date: 01.02.2019 & End date: 08.07.2019 and click on "Submit" it should get filtered between Dates also.

```
Private Sub cmdauto_Click()

Dim wsData As Worksheet

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With wsData
Select Case Me.DTPicker1
    Case Me.DTPicker1
        .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & lDateFrom, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & lDateTo
    End Select
End With

With wsData
Select Case Me.DTPicker2
    Case Me.DTPicker2
        .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=" & lDateFrom, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & lDateTo
    End Select
End With

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer since, from your comments, it seems your problem is that you are having a problem getting the data from the datepicker into your variables. There are examples on SO of doing that. In general, you would access the `.Value` property of the control.

Comment: Can you please correct in which line i need to add  "DTPicker1.Value" !!

Comment: You just need to add lines to equate your date variables to the different datepickers.

Comment: I tried by adding in "Case Me.DTPicker2.Value"  but the filter is not giving the required result

Comment: Where are you setting the variables `lDateFrom` and `lDateTo` ?

Comment: From the Userform

Comment: @sant Show the code where you are doing that.  I don't see anything that sets those two variables to a date value.

Comment: Yes...now i got it I have forgotten to set variables for lDateFrom and lDateTo !! Thank you for recognizing the issue... I will edit the Code.